# Was khutbah delivered in the Arabic language in non-Arabic speaking lands during the 4 caliphs rule?

Tags: history, jumuah, caliph

The Caliphs conquered non-muslim lands who didn't speak arabic and I assume there must have been conversions during this time as well. So, did the friday khutbah take place in arabic there or was it in the local language?

For example: Umar RA conquest of Persia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muslim_conquest_of_Persia)

> Caliph Umar ordered a full invasion of the Sasanian empire in 642,
>   which led to the complete conquest of the Sasanians around 651.

According to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasanian_Empire#Language) , Arabic was not a language in this empire

Comment: I wonder if the of extent of conversion during this early time was enough to fulfill the conditions for Jummah. The ruling is based on analogy, it would have have been simpler if the stance of the caliph\sahaba was known.

Comment: I don't think that the khutba was held in any other language as I don't know of a scholarly view of the early scholars saying otherwise. But a Friday prayer requires settlement. So an army on expedition would hardly pray more than the prayer of fear I'd assume.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no definitive answer to this question, as the available sources are not entirely clear or consistent**. However, some scholars argue that it is likely that Khutbah was delivered in the Arabic language in non-Arabic speaking territories during the reigns of the four caliphs.

One reason for this is that Arabic was the language of the Qur'an, which was central to Islam and its teachings. As the religion spread beyond Arabia, the use of Arabic likely continued, at least in some contexts. Additionally, the caliphs and other early Muslim leaders likely encouraged the use of Arabic as a way of promoting unity and reinforcing the central role of Islam in their societies.

There are also some historical records that suggest that Khutbah was indeed delivered in Arabic in non-Arabic speaking territories during the early centuries of Islam. For example, the historian Tabari, who lived in the 9th and 10th centuries, wrote that the Khutbah was delivered in Arabic in the Persian city of Ray during the time of the second caliph, Umar. Similarly, other sources suggest that Khutbah was delivered in Arabic in areas such as Egypt, Syria, and Mesopotamia during the early Islamic period.

However, it is worth noting that the use of Arabic for Khutbah may have varied depending on the local context and the linguistic diversity of the region. In some cases, local languages may have been used alongside Arabic, or even instead of it. Additionally, the extent to which Arabic was used for Khutbah may have evolved over time as Islam spread and new linguistic and cultural influences emerged.

In conclusion, while there is some evidence to suggest that Khutbah was delivered in Arabic in non-Arabic speaking territories during the reigns of the four caliphs, the historical record is complex and open to interpretation. More research is needed to fully understand how the language of Khutbah was used and evolved during this important period in Islamic history.

Answer (score 0):

The khutbah, or sermon, was primarily delivered in the Arabic language during the time of the four caliphs, who ruled the Islamic Empire from 632-661 CE. At that time, Arabic was the language of the ruling class and the language of the Qur'an, the holy book of Islam.

However, it is worth noting that during the early Islamic period, there were many non-Arabic-speaking people who converted to Islam, and they were able to learn Arabic in order to understand the Qur'an and participate in Islamic rituals. It is also possible that during the early Islamic period, some khutbahs were delivered in other languages, such as Persian, which was widely spoken in parts of the Islamic Empire.

Overall, while the khutbah was primarily delivered in Arabic during the time of the four caliphs, there may have been some exceptions depending on the local context and the linguistic abilities of the audience.
It's important to note that during the time of the four caliphs, the Islamic Empire expanded rapidly, and this expansion brought many non-Arabic-speaking people into the fold of Islam. As a result, there were many efforts to translate the Qur'an and Islamic texts into other languages so that people could understand them.

For example, during the reign of the second caliph, Umar ibn al-Khattab, the Qur'an was compiled into a standardized written form, and copies were distributed to different regions of the Islamic Empire. This helped to spread knowledge of the Qur'an and Arabic language throughout the empire, making it easier for people to learn Arabic and understand the khutbah.

In addition, during the early Islamic period, there were many prominent scholars who were not of Arab descent but were fluent in Arabic and contributed significantly to the development of Islamic thought and scholarship. One such example is Imam Bukhari, a Persian scholar who is widely considered to be one of the greatest compilers of hadith, the sayings, and actions of the Prophet Muhammad[pbuh]

Overall, while the khutbah was primarily delivered in Arabic during the time of the four caliphs, there were efforts to translate Islamic texts into other languages, and many non-Arabic-speaking people were able to learn Arabic and participate fully in Islamic rituals and practices.

Sources:

1. The History of the Khalifahs Who Took the Right Way" by Jalal al-Din
   al-Suyuti
2. The Cambridge Companion to Arabic Philosophy" edited by Peter
   Adamson